# Windows и Linux на одном компьютере, безопасность

Tags: linux, безопасность

Есть удаленный компьютер с полным захваченным доступом к Шиндоус, на этом же компьютере есть Debian, втoрaя os, какие есть варианты получить к нему доступ? Или такое невозможно? (теоретически)

Например, добавить (c помощью какой нибудь магии), в автозапуск debian какое нибудь приложение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Два месяца назад ext2fsd получил поддержку записи ext4-разделов, так что не составит никакого труда сделать с дебианом что угодно. А ещё его можно попробовать запустить в виртуальной машине.

Comment: А зашифровать всю файловую систему debian возможно? (возможно бред сморозил)

Comment: Никаких проблем нет зашифровать раздел целиком, для этого даже не надо знать что там за ФС и есть ли она вообще.

Comment: Если имелось в виду зашифровать дебиан в целях защиты, то да, возможно, но деталей я не знаю

Answer (score 0):

С винды, по-умолчанию, файловую систему Linux не прочесть. Но ломается всё, в зависимости от рук человека, его желания и свободного времени.